# Trouble with writing a program for an arithmetic teller machine that dispenses money

Tags: c

I have most of it done, but can't solve the problem with my pointers. 
Here are the instructions: Write a program for an arithmetic teller machine that dispenses money. The user should enter the amount desired (a multiple of 10 dollars) and the machine dispenses this amount using the least number of bills. The bills dispenses are 50s, 20s, and 10s.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dispense (int,int*,int*,int*);

int main (void)
{
    int money_in, bill_50, bill_20, bill_10;
    printf("Enter the amount of money: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &money_in);
    void dispense (int money_in, int *bill_50, int *bill_20, int *bill_10);

    printf(" %p\n", &bill_50);
    printf(" %p\n", &bill_20);
    printf(" %p\n", &bill_10);
return 0;
}

void dispense (int money_in, int *bill_50, int *bill_20, int *bill_10){

    *bill_50 = money_in / 50;
        (money_in % 50) / 20;
    *bill_20 = money_in / 20;
        (money_in % 20) / 10;
    *bill_10 = money_in / 10;
}
```

Comment: See my answer. If you find it helpful, the courteous thing to do on StackOverlow is to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code had a few problems:

1. Your call to `dispense()` was in the form of a prototype instead of an actual call.
2. Your `dispense()` function wouldn't compile and the math was wrong.
3. You should probably check user input to verify it's an even multiple of 10. I didn't add that code. You can probably figure that out on your own.

The code below seems to work. I normally wouldn't have done this for homework, but I was feeling generous. I hope you take the time to review the code and really learn something.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dispense(int, int*, int*, int*);

int main(void)
{
    int money_in, bill_50, bill_20, bill_10;
    printf("Enter the amount of money: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &money_in);
    dispense(money_in, &bill_50, &bill_20, &bill_10);

    printf(" %d\n", bill_50);
    printf(" %d\n", bill_20);
    printf(" %d\n", bill_10);
    return 0;
}

void dispense(int money_in, int *bill_50, int *bill_20, int *bill_10) {

    *bill_50 = money_in / 50;
    money_in -= 50 * *bill_50;
    *bill_20 = money_in / 20;
    money_in -= 20 * *bill_20;
    *bill_10 = money_in / 10;
}
```